# Combine a button and a progress bar, inline, inside grid element

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm learning Bootstrap. I have a simple grid view divided into two as follows:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">cell 1</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">cell 2</div>
</div>
```

I'd like to place a button and a progress bar into cell 2, while keeping them inline. I've started with the following:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">cell 1</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="45" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 45%">
                <span class="sr-only">45% Complete</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The button and progress bar appear, but wrapped rather than inline

[image]

where as I'd like to get (with the help of a little Photoshop) to this

[image]

I'm not sure how to progress, can you help?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/nxxw0obk/1/

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">cell 1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
            <div class="progress progressbar-container">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="45" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 45%">
                <span class="sr-only">45% Complete</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.progressbar-container{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
}
```

(P.S. I've used xs- classes because I have a small screen)

Comment: thank you for taking the time on this - appreciate it!

Comment: For Bootstrap 4 just replace `display: inline-block;` with `display: inline-flex;` and it should work as well.

Answer (score 1):

IF you add another restriction on width for the button and progress bar you should have it.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">cell 1</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-10">
            <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="45" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 45%">
                    <span class="sr-only">45% Complete</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```